# Why Django-Admin Panel did not show css and javascript in real vps?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, static-files

I have django admin panel working on a vps ( Windows Server 2012 ) , Why it is not showing any css styles or boostrap ? it is showing just html and nothing else .

Comment: How do you serve your static files? Is your DEBUG variable in settings.py set to False?

Comment: Yes , debug is false @NihalSangeeth

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/

> During development, if you use django.contrib.staticfiles, this will
>   be done automatically by runserver when DEBUG is set to True (see
>   django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve()).

So when you change `DEBUG=False` to move out of development, Django runserver will no longer automatically serve static files. 
Here is an alternate method using http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html

## whitenoise for serving staticfiles in deployment

1)  `pip install whitenoise`

2) Add `'whitenoise'` to installed_apps

3) Give `STATIC_ROOT` to a folder like:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

4) Run to collect staticfiles in `STATIC_ROOT` directory

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

5)Add `STATICFILES_STORAGE`(optional)

```
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

6) Add in middleware before everything except  `'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware'`, like:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
   ...
]
```

7)Change to `DEBUG=False` in settings.py

More details here http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html

Comment: Please ignore step 8 (editing `wsgi.py`). That was for a much older version of WhiteNoise and it will not work for newer releases.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I believe you are the owner of the project? Great work there.

Comment: @NihalSangeeth I tried your solution , but not works for me .